# Describe in a trigonometric manner the radius of circle ABD.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let $D\in BC$ in $\triangle ABC$, so that $AD$ is the bisector of $\angle BAC$. Let $r$ be the radius of the circle inscribed in $\triangle ABC$ and $R$ the radius of the circumscribed circle of $\triangle ABC$.

I am trying to solve an inequality in a triangle, and I was wondering if there are any other ways to write the radius of the circumscribed circle of $\triangle ABD$, preferably also using $R$ and $r$.

Edit: My result was wrong.

Comment: What is $p{}{}$?

Comment: $p=\cfrac{a+b+c}{2}$

Comment: Don't answer that in a comment. Edit your question so user don't have to read the comments to learn what is $p$.

Comment: @Memat "*I am trying to solve an inequality in a triangle*" $\;-\;$ You should post the actual problem you are trying to solve, not an isolated step which may or may not be the best way to solve it.

Comment: Your formula for the circumradius is not valid : consider for example the case of an equilateral triangle $a=b=c=1$ : we would have $R_1=1$ instead of $\frac12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following figure :

[image]

where point $E$ is located at the intersection of line $AB$ and the parallel line to $AD$ (the line bissector) drawn from $C$. Let $R$ and $R'$ be the resp. radii of the circumcircles of $BDA$ et $BCE$.

Let $\alpha = \angle BAD = \angle DAC$. This angle can be found at two other places $\alpha = \angle AEC = \angle ECA$. As a consequence, triangle $EAC$ is isosceles, which implies $AE=AC=b$.

Besides, [sine law](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Law_of_Sines) in triangle $BCE$ gives :

$$\frac{a}{\sin \alpha}= \cdots = 2R' \tag{1}$$

But the small circle is the image of the big one by the homothety with center  $B$ and ratio factor : $\frac{c}{c+b}$.

Therefore :

$$R=\frac{c}{c+b}R'\tag{2}$$

Finally, taking (1) into account,

$$R=\frac{ac}{2(c+b)\sin \alpha}\tag{3}$$

Comment: Any comment ?....

Comment: Thanks! This is actually exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Note that center of inscribed circle is on bisector of all three angles. Also there are two inscribed circle , one in triangle ABD and other in triangle ADC. let:

$BC=a$, $AC=b$, $AB=c$, Mark centers of incribed circle ABC, ABD and ACD as $O$, $O_1$ and $O_2$ respectively.Also $r$, $r_1$ and $r_2$ as their radius. Also:

$\angle BAC=\alpha$, $\angle ABC=\beta$ and $\angle ACB=\gamma$.

In triangle ACD radius$r_2=O_2E$(E on AC) is:

$r_2=AE\tan\frac {\alpha}4\space\space\space\space(1)$

$AE=(AC=b)-EC$

$EC=\frac {r_2}{\tan \frac{\gamma}2}$

$\Rightarrow AE=b-\frac {r_2}{\tan \frac{\gamma}2}\space\space\space\space(2)$

putting (2) in (1) we finally get:

$r_2=\frac{b\tan \frac{\alpha}4\tan \frac{\gamma}2}{\tan \frac{\alpha}4+\tan \frac{\gamma}2}$

Similarly you find:

$r_1=\frac{c\tan \frac{\alpha}4\tan \frac{\beta}2}{\tan \frac{\alpha}4+\tan \frac{\beta}2}$

You can find angles using this formula:

$\frac a{\sin \alpha}=\frac b{\sin \beta}=\frac c{\sin \gamma}=2R$